# Mac Resource editor in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, resource-file

I have some OLD programs that I'm mantaining. They still use resource files with resource forks, and all that hideousness.

My co-worker uses a 10.3 box that can still run mac classic programs and RezEdit.

I used to use ReSorcerer, but it doesn't seem to work very will in 10.6.

Does anyone have any recommendations for programs to use?

ETA: I need to be able to edit DITLs in a wysiwyg manner. So, it has to have some tools for moving around buttons, etc. Rezilla seems to only give me a list of window objects, and resknife seems to only give me a hex-dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run RezEdit on an emulator like [SheepShaver](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/). Works on Intel Macs.

Comment: that looks promising, for a couple of other things we run as well... Now I need to figure out how to get a ROM file...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [Rezilla](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/23349)

Comment: Since Rezilla and ResKnife won't work for you, your only other options are to use something like SheepSaver and run either Resourcerer or RezEdit on it or use an older machine on which those applications worked better.

Of course, you could also consider dropping support for these old programs or update them to modern Cocoa applications, using Interface Builder.

Comment: Yeah, Yeah, Yeah, I've been trying for 3 years to get my company to re-write our main product, but "it's too big" and "we have things to do that actually EARN MONEY NOW" etc.

Comment: Well, then, I would suggest obtaining an old machine use ResEdit and Resourcerer or see if SheepShaver will work for you. I am pretty sure those are your only good options.